# Get only values of dynamic JSON in comma separated string in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this dynamic JSON -

```
    {
    "SMSPhone": [
        "SMS Phone Number is not valid"
    ],
    "VoicePhone": [
        "Voice Phone Number is not valid"
    ]
}
```

I need only values as comma separated string. Also, its dynamic so, i do not know the key names.

Desired result - SMS Phone Number is not valid,Voice Phone Number is not valid

Code i tried -

```
let res=JSON.parse(Jsondata);
   res.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element)
    //logic
  });
```

I am getting following error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` is an object, so you can't use `forEach`.  If you want to iterate over an object's values, you need to do something like:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(Jsondata)) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to achieve here. But you can't use `forEach` on an object. `forEach` is used to loop through data in an array.
In your case, I would use `object.entries()` as shown below to achieve my goal.

```js
const data = {
    "SMSPhone": [
        "SMS Phone Number is not valid"
    ],
    "VoicePhone": [
        "Voice Phone Number is not valid"
    ]
};


for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```